# Javascript Control

Tags: javascript, debugging, variables

I have a project for going to using a few JavaScript control structures. First, use logical operators within an "if" statement to validate an email address and comments. Second, use a "switch" statement to efficiently check multiple "cases" on which to take some action. Third, use a "for loop" to generate a set of random numbers. I have complete the code but encounter some error, if anyone can help me out

```js
// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function validates the data and returns a Boolean.
function process() {
    'use strict';

    // Variable to represent validity:
    var okay = true;
    
    // Get form references:
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
 // ----get a reference to the comments element here
    var comments =document.getElementsByName('comments');
    // Validate the email address:
  
  //----check email value's length to be less than 8  
    //---- check to make sure the @ symbol is present
    if (!email || !email.value|| (email.value.length < 8) || (email.value.indexOf(‘@’) == -1)) {
        okay = false;
    alert(‘Please enter a valid email address!’);

}

    // Validate the comments:
    //---- begin the if statement here to check for existence of comments and comments.value
        if (!comments || !comments.value
        || (comments.value.indexOf(‘<’) != -1) ) {
            okay = false;
        alert(‘Please enter your comments, without any HTML!’);

        }
    
    // Call the showNumbers() function
    showNumbers();
 // Call the calculate() function
 calculate();
        
    // Return false to prevent submission:
 return false;
    
} // End of process() function.

// Function performs the calculation and returns false.
function calculate() {
    
    // Be strict:
    'use strict';

    // Variable to store the total cost:
    var cost;

    // Get a reference to the form elements:
    var type = document.getElementById('type');
    var years = document.getElementById('years');
    
    // Convert the year to a number:
 if (years && years.value) { //----check that year and year's value property have non-FALSE values
        years = parseInt(years.value, 10);
    }
    
    // Check for valid data: 
   if (type && type.value && years && (years > 0) ) {
        
        // Determine the base cost:
       // use the switch conditional here and make type.value the condition for it
        switch(type.value){
            case 'basic':
                cost = 10.00;
                break;
            case 'premium':
                cost = 15.00;
                break;
            case 'gold':
                cost = 20.00;
                break;
            case 'platinum':
                cost = 25.00;
                break;
     // add titanium level here
            case 'titanium':
                cost = 30.00;
                break;

    
        } // End of switch.
        
        // Factor in the number of years:
        cost *= years;
        
        // Discount multiple years:
        if (years > 1) {
            cost *= .80; // 80%
        }
        
        // Show the total amount:
        document.getElementById('cost').value = '$' + cost.toFixed(2);
        
    } else { // Show an error:
        document.getElementById('cost').value = 'Please enter valid values.';
    }
    
    // Return false to prevent submission:
    return false;
    
} // End of calculate() function.

// This function is called by the process() function.
// Function finds six random numbers and displays them in a paragraph.
function showNumbers() {
    'use strict';

    // Variable to store the lucky numbers:
    var numbers = '';

 // Get the numbers:
 // set up a for loop that will start and 0 and loop 6 times
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        numbers += parseInt((Math.random() * 100), 10) + ' ';
    }

    // Show the numbers:
 var output = document.getElementById('output');
 if (output.textContent !== undefined) {
  output.textContent = numbers;
 } else {
  output.innerText = numbers;
 }

} // End of showNumbers() function.


// Initial setup:
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = process;
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Here are the errors I get when I run the program:

```
 11 errors  6 warnings
Line 17: Unexpected '‘'.
Line 18: Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.
Line 19: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 17 and instead saw 'alert'.
Line 19: Unexpected '‘'.
Line 21: Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'.
Line 25: Expected ')' and instead saw 'if'.
Line 26: Bad line breaking before '||'.
Line 26: Unexpected '‘'.
Line 27: Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.
Line 28: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 26 and instead saw 'alert'.
Line 28: Unexpected '‘'.
Line 30: Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'.
Line 33: Expected ')' and instead saw 'showNumbers'.
Line 33: Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.
Line 35: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 17 and instead saw 'calculate'.
Line 35: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lot of "stylized" quotes.  For example:

```
email.value.indexOf(‘@’)
```

Those aren't valid for code.  (They're usually used in word processors for documents.  Not sure how you got them into your code.)  You want to use proper quotes instead:

```
email.value.indexOf('@')
```

There are several places in your code where this is happening, you'll want to fix all of them.

Comment: I see there is several lines have the same error, but i'm not familar with the JavaScript syntax error and the code i have was from my textbook example, i must implement wrong

Comment: @chancissy: Yes, there are several lines with the same error.  You'll need to fix all of them.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
email.value.indexOf(‘@’) == -1)
```

to this:

> email.value.indexOf('@') == -1)

Comment: Ok, i have go in and changed this line, now it gives me 8 errors and have one error shows i missed a semicolon. but i have a semicolon in there. I am really confuse